# How to insert a new property into a object using MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object

I would like to add another property, `Toggle` inside of my object (I want to do this for both Anti Channels & Roles which is I included the schema here).

## Code

```js
await config.findOneAndUpdate({ GuildID: GuildId }, { $set: { AntiChannels: { Toggle: "Enabled" } } }, { returnOriginal: true })
```

## Schema

```js
AntiChannels: {
 Toggle: { type: String },
 Actions: { Type: Number },
 Time: { Type: Number },
},
AntiRoles: {
 Toggle: { type: String },
 Actions: { Type: Number },
 Time: { Type: Number },
}
```

[image: I would like to add my Toggle property inside this Object but it just removes everything else in the Object.]

I thought that `returnOriginal` would return the original data in the document as well but it does not seem like it does that. How would I go about doing this?

Also, what happens when I execute this code is that everything in the the Image above, gets removed and the Toggle property is added. I just want to include the other properties as well not remove them. Thanks :)

Comment: Try: `await config.findOneAndUpdate({ GuildID: GuildId }, { $set: { AntiChannels.Toggle: "Enabled"} }, { returnOriginal: true })`

Comment: The correct code sample you have here actually gives syntax error, the correct code would be: `await config.findOneAndUpdate({ GuildID: GuildId },{ $set: { 'AntiChannels.Toggle': 'Enabled' } },{ returnOriginal: true });`

Nonetheless, this actually worked, I thought I tried something like this before but thanks :)